# What is the meaning and difference of XXX-facing and XXX-oriented?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage, terminology

What is the meaning and difference of XXX-facing and XXX-oriented?

examples:

```
customer-facing
document-oriented
```

Answer (score 1):

These are what are called "terms of art" or "jargon", and have meanings that may not be entirely as implied by strict dictionary definitions.

When speaking of computer systems, a "customer-facing" subsystem is that part of the system that the customers interact with - if you visualize the system as a "magic wall", with the customers on one side and the programmers, database administrators, and so on on the other side, the "customer-facing" side is the side that the customers can see.

"Document-oriented" means that the various subsystems are written to handle *documents* (probably meaning unstructured data) - functionality will be designed to manipulate this type of data, and will offer options to the user that make sense for this type of data. (I'm not explaining this well; I'm not sure it can be put simply.) A not-entirely-accurate analogy would be fast food stores - compare McDonald's to KFC: McDonald's is "hamburger-oriented", but KFC is "chicken-oriented".